# Retrieving cross-domain JSON data, Javascript/JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jsonp

I did some research on retrieving cross domain JSON data, but when I implemented it, the code didn't work. Doing some more research, I found that browsers don't let websites retrieve data from a different host due to security reasons. I found an answer that said I should use JSONP, but it still wasn't working? This was my code.

```
function getWeather(location){
   $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + location + "&appid=/*my usual app id is here*/&callback=?", function(result){
       //response data are now in the result variable
       alert(result.weather[0].description);
       var changeW = document.getElementById("theweathertext");
       changeW.innerHTML = "The current weather at your destination: " + result.weather[0].description +".";
});
}
```

When I test the code, the browser isn't letting me retrieve the data? How would I fix this? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: This code was working when I was testing it locally, but when I did a live launch preview, it didn't work. Could this be some other problem?

Comment: What is the error message? What did you learn from researching said error message when related to jsonp?

Comment: Works fine for me if I write my API key. Check console for errors.

Comment: I was getting response code 0. And this code was in fact working on my local console, but when I published the website temporarily, it didn't work.

Comment: Oh! I found the issue. I use the editor brackets from brackets.io, and there was a problem with the live launch preview. I had to tweak some setting... now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work if you provide a valid apikey:

```
$.getJSON(
    'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=lisbon&callback=?',
    function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

EDIT: It currently gives me 401 code which means i have no rights to access this endpoint. That is why i'm suggesting to use a valid api key.